# What does if (fstreamTest) check for? Is it checking for a specific flag?

Tags: c++, fstream

In the following code

```
fstream testFile;
testFile.open("test.txt", ios::in);

if (testFile)
cout << "This if statement is true";
```

What does C++ check for in order to return `true` from `if(testfile)`?
Is it checking if `testFile.goodbit()` is true?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can lookup the definitions... http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool or http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/ as mentioned.   In the end, its invoking a method on the fstream class that is returning true or false.

The documentation on the method says :

```
Returns true if the stream has no errors occurred and is ready
of I/O operations. Specifically, returns !fail()
```

Another version of the documentation says :

```
Returns whether an error flag is set (either failbit or badbit).

Notice that this function does not return the same as member good,
but the opposite of member fail.
```

Answer (score 3):

> What does C++ check for in order to return true from if(testfile)?

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool):

> Checks whether the stream has no errors. 
> 1) Returns a null pointer if
>   `fail()` returns true, otherwise returns a non-null pointer. This
>   pointer is implicitly convertible to `bool` and may be used in boolean
>   contexts. (until `C++11`) 
> 2) Returns `true` if the stream has no errors and is ready for
>   I/O operations. Specifically, returns `!fail()`. (since `C++11`)

1) `operator void*() const;` (*until* C++11)
2) `explicit operator bool() const;` (*since* C++11)

If the stream has no errors it will return `true`, otherwise it will return `false`.

This makes it possible to do things like:

```
while(stream >> value) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Should be worth mentioning that 1) applies until c++11 and 2) does beyond